# phonegap accelerometer feature is not working for windows phone 8

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8

I was trying the accelerometer function from phonegap for windows phone 8 (lumia 920).
I already included the plugin for the accelerometer:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
</Capabilities>
```

However, I still did not get any output. The codes are obtained from the phonegap documentation for windows phone 8. Can someone tell me what went wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acceleration Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>getCurrentAcceleration</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

that happened to me too,try the same with some other version of cordova(eg 2.5.0).
sometimes it happens with 2.5.0 version too.i tried to use the event code then run it and then use the code you want to run,it will work.
reason is quite unclear why this happens.